# My computer is not compatible with TV

Tags: hdmi

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 computer and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it. My problem is when I connect it to the tv I cannot see the film I want to watch just my desktop wallpaper and I don't know what to do. Please suggest me what to do.

Comment: I figured out what's the problem but thanks:)

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like your TV is acting as a second monitor. This is the default behavior when you plug in a second screen.

If you want to show the movie on the TV, drag the player window out to either the right or the left of the laptop monitor. You'll see it slide into the TV screen on one of the sides.

Go to **System Settings --> Displays**  and you'll see the monitor arrangement as two rectangles. If you want, you can also turn on **Mirror Displays** which will make the TV and laptop show the exact same image.